# Internet Resolver on AWS can't be deleted

Tags: amazon-route53, resolver

[Internet Resolver][1]

Hi ,
How can I delete this , it been trying but I am not getting any suitable way to delete it .Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MigP.png

Answer (score 1):

If you are using amazon provided DNS in your VPC then dot (.) rule will be the default for internet resolver pointing to amazon DNS server. You can not delete this as it  will be assigned to the default VPC in that AWS account. However you can override that association with your VPC is in question and you can have your custom dot(.) forwarding rule pointing to your own DNS server or another server in the internet such as 8.8.8.8. and have that rules associated with all your VPC to have DNS query resolved accordingly.

However if you are using a custom server make sure you have a system rule in place to resolve amazon owned domain name(amazonaws.com) privately. and associate that system rule with all of your VPCs.